# How does glassdoor facebook app attaches multiple images in newsfeed story?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-opengraph

I know how to post via fb api and i know all the stuff about meta tags. But i am unable to post story to newsfeed by attaching multiple user images.like glassdoor app does. An example of the newsfeed story i want to publish is - 
user activated 4 connections on appnamespace
(with 4 images of users attached in a single news feed)
an example is also attached as an image screenshot.
[image]